# How can I grep date value in complex pattern?

Tags: regex, grep

I use this grep for date:

```
grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d{9}'
```

It's work for this:

```
xxx_yyy/zzz/www201504091545-xxx.tar.gz
```

But I can't grep date value when line does not have 201, like this:

```
/data/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/T111504091545.ZET.gz
/data/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/Z251504081345.YAT.gz
/data/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/ZT51504071235.YAT.gz
/data/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/ZA51403021131.YAT.gz
```

1504.... is date value(or 1403, 1404...). And after date value have .ZET.gz or .YAT.gz.

Before date, have 3 characters(number and/or not).

How can I do that? Thank you.

Outputs:

```
1504091545
1504081345
1504071235
1403021131
```

Comment: try `grep -oP '(?<!\d)\d{12}'`

Comment: But before date have numbers too, and it's not static. So it can be 12 or 13 or 14.

Comment: Then try `grep -oP '\d{12}\b'` to match all cases with 12 digits before a word boundary.

Comment: @Ric: What's your expected output from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `grep`:

```
grep -oP '\d{10}(?=\.)' file
1504091545
1504081345
1504071235
1403021131
```

Or little more restrictive as per your question:

```
grep -oP '\d{10}(?=\.(YAT|ZET))' file
```